# Should I change this excel formula using IF, OR, and AND into one that uses IFS? If so how?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this formula in excel:

```
=IF(H2<3.5,0,  
    IF(D2="FIB",  
        IF(AND(T2>='Sheet1'!L5, T2<='Sheet1'!M5), 'Sheet1'!K5,  
        IF(AND(T2>='Sheet1'!L6,T2<='Sheet1'!M6), 'Sheet1'!K6,  
        IF(T2>='Sheet1'!L7, 'Sheet1'!K7)))),  
    IF(D2="FIS",  
        IF(T2<='Sheet1'!O5, 'Sheet1'!K5,  
        IF(AND(T2>='Sheet1'!N6,T2<='Sheet1'!O6), 'Sheet1'!K6))),  
    IF(OR(D2="FOB", "FOS"),  
        IF(T2<='Sheet1'!Q5, 'Sheet1'!K5,  
        IF(AND(T2>='Sheet1'!P6, T2<='Sheet1'!Q6), 'Sheet1'!K6))),  
    IF(D2="EG",  
        IF(T2<='Sheet1'!U5, 'Sheet1'!S5,  
        IF(T2>='Sheet1'!T6, 'Sheet1'!S6)))  
)
```

But it is saying I have too many arguments. I think I might need to use IFS but when I tried it (remembering to use =TRUE) it is still saying there are too many arguments.  Can anyone modify my formula so that it will work?
This is the logic behind the formula:
If H2 is less than 3.5, just output 0
If D=FIB, then check to see if that value is between the values in sheet1 or above or below (i know that portion is right)
And then this gets repeated based on if D2 equals FIS, FOB OR FOS, and EG.

Comment: "i know that portion is right" - I think you're wrong on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Nesting IF Functions

- The IF function has 3 arguments and although the 3rd is optional, not supplying its parameter is the same as setting it to `FALSE`. You didn't supply it 5 times which may have led to confusion.
- In the end, it mostly boils down to having the correct number of parentheses (**your number is correct!**) and putting them in the right place (**not correct!**).
- Also, see the indentation in the readable version. It makes much more sense to me.

**Readable**

```
=IF(H2<3.5,
    0,
    IF(D2="FIB",
        IF(AND(T2>=Sheet1!L5,T2<=Sheet1!M5),
            Sheet1!K5,
            IF(AND(T2>=Sheet1!L6,T2<=Sheet1!M6),
                Sheet1!K6,
                IF(T2>=Sheet1!L7,Sheet1!K7,FALSE))),
        IF(D2="FIS",
            IF(T2<=Sheet1!O5,
                Sheet1!K5,
                IF(AND(T2>=Sheet1!N6,T2<=Sheet1!O6),Sheet1!K6,FALSE)),
            IF(OR(D2="FOB","FOS"),
                IF(T2<=Sheet1!Q5,
                    Sheet1!K5,
                    IF(AND(T2>=Sheet1!P6,T2<=Sheet1!Q6),Sheet1!K6,FALSE)),
                IF(D2="EG",
                    IF(T2<=Sheet1!U5,
                        Sheet1!S5,
                        IF(T2>=Sheet1!T6,Sheet1!S6,FALSE)),
                    FALSE)))))
```

**Compact**

```
=IF(H2<3.5,0,
    IF(D2="FIB",
        IF(AND(T2>=Sheet1!L5,T2<=Sheet1!M5),Sheet1!K5,
            IF(AND(T2>=Sheet1!L6,T2<=Sheet1!M6),Sheet1!K6,
                IF(T2>=Sheet1!L7,Sheet1!K7,FALSE))),
    IF(D2="FIS",
        IF(T2<=Sheet1!O5,Sheet1!K5,
            IF(AND(T2>=Sheet1!N6,T2<=Sheet1!O6),Sheet1!K6,FALSE)),
    IF(OR(D2="FOB","FOS"),
        IF(T2<=Sheet1!Q5,Sheet1!K5,
            IF(AND(T2>=Sheet1!P6,T2<=Sheet1!Q6),Sheet1!K6,FALSE)),
    IF(D2="EG",
        IF(T2<=Sheet1!U5,Sheet1!S5,
            IF(T2>=Sheet1!T6,Sheet1!S6,FALSE)),
    FALSE)))))
```

**Compact Without `FALSE`**

(to compare with your formula)

```
=IF(H2<3.5,0,
    IF(D2="FIB",
        IF(AND(T2>=Sheet1!L5,T2<=Sheet1!M5),Sheet1!K5,
            IF(AND(T2>=Sheet1!L6,T2<=Sheet1!M6),Sheet1!K6,
                IF(T2>=Sheet1!L7,Sheet1!K7))),
    IF(D2="FIS",
        IF(T2<=Sheet1!O5,Sheet1!K5,
            IF(AND(T2>=Sheet1!N6,T2<=Sheet1!O6),Sheet1!K6)),
    IF(OR(D2="FOB","FOS"),
        IF(T2<=Sheet1!Q5,Sheet1!K5,
            IF(AND(T2>=Sheet1!P6,T2<=Sheet1!Q6),Sheet1!K6)),
    IF(D2="EG",
        IF(T2<=Sheet1!U5,Sheet1!S5,
            IF(T2>=Sheet1!T6,Sheet1!S6)))))))
```

**IFS (Compact and Readable)**

```
=IF(H2<3.5,0,
    IFS(D2="FIB",
            IF(AND(T2>=Sheet1!L5,T2<=Sheet1!M5),Sheet1!K5,
                IF(AND(T2>=Sheet1!L6,T2<=Sheet1!M6),Sheet1!K6,
                    IF(T2>=Sheet1!L7,Sheet1!K7,FALSE))),
        D2="FIS",
            IF(T2<=Sheet1!O5,Sheet1!K5,
                IF(AND(T2>=Sheet1!N6,T2<=Sheet1!O6),Sheet1!K6,FALSE)),
        OR(D2="FOB","FOS"),
            IF(T2<=Sheet1!Q5,Sheet1!K5,
                IF(AND(T2>=Sheet1!P6,T2<=Sheet1!Q6),Sheet1!K6,FALSE)),
        D2="EG",
            IF(T2<=Sheet1!U5,Sheet1!S5,
                IF(T2>=Sheet1!T6,Sheet1!S6,FALSE)),
        TRUE,FALSE))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first `IF` has 6 parameters when it is only meant to have three. And each of your inner-most `IF`s have only 2.

You should fix those first.

There is no detail in your question as what you're trying to compute or what the cells mean, etc, so I'm not able to give you a corrected formula.

Here is a better breakdown of your current forumla.

```
=
    IF(
        H2<3.5,
        0,
        IF(
            D2="FIB"
            IF(
                AND(T2>='Sheet1'!L5,T2<='Sheet1'!M5),
                'Sheet1'!K5,
                IF(
                    AND(T2>='Sheet1'!L6,T2<='Sheet1'!M6),
                    'Sheet1'!K6,
                    IF(
                        T2>='Sheet1'!L7,
                        'Sheet1'!K7,
                        **MISSING**
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        **EXTRA**IF(
            D2="FIS",
            IF(
                T2<='Sheet1'!O5,
                'Sheet1'!K5,
                IF(
                    AND(T2>='Sheet1'!N6,T2<='Sheet1'!O6),
                    'Sheet1'!K6,
                    **MISSING**
                )
            )
        ),
        **EXTRA**IF(
            OR(D2="FOB","FOS"),
            IF(
                T2<='Sheet1'!Q5,
                'Sheet1'!K5,
                IF(
                    AND(T2>='Sheet1'!P6,T2<='Sheet1'!Q6),
                    'Sheet1'!K6,
                    **MISSING**
                )
            )
        ),
        **EXTRA**IF(
            D2="EG",
            IF(
                T2<='Sheet1'!U5,
                'Sheet1'!S5,
                IF(
                    T2>='Sheet1'!T6,
                    'Sheet1'!S6,
                    **MISSING**
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

---

I took the logic that you described in the question and built this template:

```
=
    IF(
        H2<3.5,
        0,
        IF(
            D2="FIB",
            1,
            IF(
                D2="FIS",
                2,
                IF(
                    OR(D2="FOB",D2="FOS"),
                    3,
                    IF(
                        D2="EG",
                        4,
                        5
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

That's a correctly balanced set of `IF` functions.

You just need to replace the `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, and `5` with the values you need. I didn't understand the rest of your description in the question to be able to get those right, but the above should help.

Here it is again in a form you can just type in.

```
=IF(H2<3.5,0,IF(D2="FIB",1,IF(D2="FIS",2,IF(OR(D2="FOB",D2="FOS"),3,IF(D2="EG",4,5)))))
```

Comment: I added some logic to the question.  Hope that helps a bit.